# How to set custom thread pool for handling particular request in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, multithreading, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

`Java 11`, `SpringBoot 2.5.1 WebFlux`

There is a method that is supposed to consume a lot of memory during the execution. I would like to configure a limited amount of threads that can execute it to avoid too much parallel executions for it.
For example, I expect that there will be a thread pool with 2 threads. And even when 100 requests `GET /hello` arrive simultaneously, only 2 of them should start processing of `service.resourceConsumingMethod()`, others just stay in a queue until one of the threads is available in the thread pool.

Tried to create a custom scheduler and use it in `publishOn` and `subscribeOn`, but without the expected effect: when 5 requests are sent approximately at the same time, then they all start execution in parallel.

Most definitely, I misuse `publishOn` and `subscribeOn`, because it is not completely clear for me how they work internally.

Here is the two examples where the `resourceConsumingMethod` is replaced with `sleep(40000)`. The 4 requests `POST /hit` were sent almost in the same time.

Both examples share this setup

```
@RestController 
class MyController {

  final MyService service; 
  final Scheduler scheduler; 

  MyController(MyService service) {
    this.service = service;
    this.scheduler = Schedulers.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2));
    this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("mylogger");
  }

  ...
}
```

The first one works as expected.

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/hit")
  Object post(){
    var uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    return Flux
               .defer(() -> {
                 logger.warn(uuid + ": start file content");
                 return Flux.fromIterable(List.of(1,2,3));
               })
               .collectList()
               .map(l -> {
                 logger.warn(uuid + ": sleep start");
                 try {
                   Thread.sleep(40000);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   throw new RuntimeException(e);
                 }
                 logger.warn(uuid + ": sleep __end");
                 return l.size();
               })
               .subscribeOn(scheduler);
  }


2021-06-14 23:59:09.838 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [WARN ] mylogger - 2c2c0261516b: start file content
2021-06-14 23:59:09.840 [pool-1-thread-2 ] [WARN ] mylogger - 2c2c0261516b: sleep start
2021-06-14 23:59:14.352 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [WARN ] mylogger - dde231c06b1f: start file content
2021-06-14 23:59:14.353 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [WARN ] mylogger - dde231c06b1f: sleep start
2021-06-14 23:59:49.842 [pool-1-thread-2 ] [WARN ] mylogger - 2c2c0261516b: sleep __end
2021-06-14 23:59:49.865 [pool-1-thread-2 ] [WARN ] mylogger - c62325ebe562: start file content
2021-06-14 23:59:49.865 [pool-1-thread-2 ] [WARN ] mylogger - f6ab8da49f05: start file content
2021-06-14 23:59:49.865 [pool-1-thread-2 ] [WARN ] mylogger - c62325ebe562: sleep start
2021-06-14 23:59:54.353 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [WARN ] mylogger - dde231c06b1f: sleep __end
2021-06-14 23:59:54.354 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [WARN ] mylogger - f6ab8da49f05: sleep start
2021-06-14 00:00:29.865 [pool-1-thread-2 ] [WARN ] mylogger - c62325ebe562: sleep __end
2021-06-14 00:00:34.357 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [WARN ] mylogger - f6ab8da49f05: sleep __end
```

The second one allows to start all requests processing immediately. An they execute not only in the custom scheduler, but in `boundedElastic` also (See logs). Obviously the problem is related to `file.content()` that somehow affects the whole chain of publishers. Even `file.content().subscribeOn(scheduler)` does not help.

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/hanga", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
   Object post(){
      @RequestPart("file") FilePart file
  ) {
    var uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    return Flux
               .defer(() -> {
                 logger.warn(uuid + ": start file content");
                 return file.content().subscribeOn(scheduler);
               })
               .map(DataBuffer::asByteBuffer)
               .collect(ByteArrayOutputStream::new, (stream, buffer) -> {
                 try {
                   stream.write(buffer.array());
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                   throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
                 }
               })
               .map(l -> {
                 logger.warn(uuid + ": sleep start");
                 try {
                   Thread.sleep(40000);
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   throw new RuntimeException(e);
                 }
                 logger.warn(uuid + ": sleep __end");
                 return l.size();
               })
               .subscribeOn(scheduler);
  }


2021-06-14 00:08:37.289 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [WARN ] mylogger - 59dd5283131a: start file content
2021-06-14 00:08:37.600 [boundedElastic-4] [WARN ] mylogger - 59dd5283131a: sleep start
2021-06-14 00:08:38.184 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [WARN ] mylogger - 5fe66ec1a47a: start file content
2021-06-14 00:08:38.376 [boundedElastic-3] [WARN ] mylogger - 5fe66ec1a47a: sleep start
2021-06-14 00:08:39.805 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [WARN ] mylogger - 859c2d65dff3: start file content
2021-06-14 00:08:40.004 [boundedElastic-2] [WARN ] mylogger - 859c2d65dff3: sleep start
2021-06-14 00:08:41.956 [pool-1-thread-1 ] [WARN ] mylogger - 8b2220a92578: start file content
2021-06-14 00:08:42.209 [boundedElastic-5] [WARN ] mylogger - 8b2220a92578: sleep start
2021-06-14 00:09:17.601 [boundedElastic-4] [WARN ] mylogger - 59dd5283131a: sleep __end
2021-06-14 00:09:18.377 [boundedElastic-3] [WARN ] mylogger - 5fe66ec1a47a: sleep __end
2021-06-14 00:09:20.005 [boundedElastic-2] [WARN ] mylogger - 859c2d65dff3: sleep __end
2021-06-14 00:09:22.209 [boundedElastic-5] [WARN ] mylogger - 8b2220a92578: sleep __end
```

**How to implement intention of a custom thread pool usage for a particular request?**

Comment: How do you observe that they start parallelly? Do you have a log somewhere? Do you put a debug breakpoint? I'm asking because at first glance I don't see any obvious issue and it's possible only the observation is incorrect.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Updated the question. Actually this problem appears only in a special case. The simplest example works as expected.

Comment: I see. There are multiple `subscribeOn`s in the chain, that's the reason you see this behaviour. Once the second `subscribeOn` is reached (the one inside `defer`), the scheduler thread used in the first one is let go and ready to be used by another subscriber.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi The `subscribeOn` inside `defer` does not affect the situation. I added it while investigating the problem. We can remove it and see a similar log. The whole part with `defer` was added as a try to isolate `file.contents()` effect: initially I started with just `file.contents()` instead of `Flux.defer(()->file.contents() ... )`. Actually, now I feel much less confident in what is going on there :))) Looks like the internal mechanics of `file.content()` breaks the external chain processing; it is surprising for me.

Comment: yeah, if any of the flow changes threads somewhere, then this technique won't work

Comment: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/bulkhead - resilience4j has support for concurrency limit with Reactor, although it throws exception instead of waiting but you might combine it with retry to make it work

Comment: What if you use concatMap(file.content())? I havent try it yet, but it waits the result of the inner publisher and after then it starts process the next one from the same stream. If you subscribe on the the sceduler with 2 thread, all other call will be queued.  Note that this may not work, because file.content may release the thread until the publisher starts publishing the content. In this case, other item can be processed.  I dont know the implementation detail of the filepart, though it is important here. But give this a try.